# Sequence $a_1=2$ and $a_n=\frac{2}{1+a_{n-1}}$ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence with $a_1=2$ and $a_n=\frac{a_1}{1+a_{n-1}}$, I have to check whether this sequence is convergent or divergent.

I have reached the conclusion till now that its subsequence $a_{2n}$ is an increasing sequence and bounded above, while the subsequence $a_{2n-1}$ is a decreasing sequence and bounded below.
So, both the subsequences are convergent.
But I am not able to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n}$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n-1}$.
Can you help me to proceed further
or maybe find another way to show its convergence or divergence?

Comment: Hello :) Is it true, that $a_1$ is in the nominator? Then you can write $a_n=\frac{2}{1+a_{n-1}}$.

Comment: @Jochen Yeah I've changed it, you can write it like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_{2n} \to a$ and $a_{2n-1} \to b$ then $a=\frac 2 {1+b}$ and $b=\frac 2 {1+a}$. Using these two equations show that $a=b$